# calling async task from activity via button ... progressdialog apears after activity has switched to another activity

Tags: android, asynchronous, task, progressdialog

i´m sitting fot hours now to get a progressdialog running....

i took a look at so many examples here on stackoverflow and on other sites.

The Problem:

I´m putting an progress dialog to an activity and hand it over to an async task when a button is pressed. 
When the button is pressed the activity is shown about 2-3 seconds without an progressdialog, after it switched to the other activity, the progressdialog shows and terminates after async task has finished. 
Coreographer tells me , that the main activity .. bla bla ..

```
// Get Position Button
    getPosition = (Button) vg.findViewById(R.id.getPosition);
    getPosition.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isAirplaneModeOn(PositionActivity.this) != true) {
                try {
                    // System.out.println("Airplanemode off!");
                    if (gpsFunc.canGetLocation()) {
                        SharedPreferences gps = PositionActivity.this
                                .getSharedPreferences(prefName,
                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String latlon = gps.getString("coordinates", null);

                        if (latlon != null) {
                            String[] split = latlon.split(";");
                            callWienerLinien();
                            latitude = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                            longitude = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
                            pressed = (TextView) vg
                                    .findViewById(R.id.pressed);
                            long start = new Date().getTime();
                            TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
                            tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
                            long end = new Date().getTime();

                            System.out.println(end-start);

                        } else {
                            pressed.setText("Bitte Position setzen.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        buildAlertMessageNoDataNetwork();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errorOccuredMessage();
                }
            } else {
                pressed.setText("Bitte Flugzeugmodus deaktivieren.");
            }
        }

    });

public void callWienerLinien(){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading ...");
    pt = new PublicTransport(pd,this);
    pt.execute("http://webservice.qando.at/2.0/webservice.ft");
}
```

this is the async task

```
    public PublicTransport(ProgressDialog pd,Context context){
    this.pd = pd;
    this.context = context;
    getLatLonDestination();
    getLatLonOrigin();
}



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("onpre");
        pd.show();          
    }


        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<PublicTransportBean> al) {
        System.out.println(al.get(0).getTripDuration());
        System.out.println("onpostExec");
        pd.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: What do `getLatLonDestination()` and `getLatLonOrigin()`? Does it take long?

Comment: hi ....  they get the gps coords .... it takes 2 ms

Answer (score 1):

Don't show the Progressdialog within the Thread, in which you run the background task. I had the same issue and did the following:

1. Prepare the Dialog
2. Show the Dialog
3. Start the background task

EDIT:

Try to call the ProgressDialog as below:

> ```
>       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {              
>             @Override
>             public void run() {
>             final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(cont);
>             progressDialog.setMessage("Progress");
>             progressDialog.show();
>             }
>         });
> ```

Comment: hello ..thanks for the quick answer... i show the dialog now before i execute the async task .... same thing :-( ... activity is frozen --> activity switches to the other activity --> dialog shows

Comment: I edited my answer and hope that this finally does the trick for you.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me ;-) ... i solved it .. see below

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem ....

i´m calling the

```
 TabActivity tabs = (TabActivity) getParent();
                    tabs.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

in the postexecute of the async task.
Working perfect ..... two lines of code and 13 hours of studying :-(

Comment: Alright, glad you managed to fix it. I guess you can accept your own answer in order to show people the real solution.

Comment: i tried ;-) but it tells me, that i have to wait till tomorrow ;-)